# Take a snapshot on a view contains UIDatePicker

Tags: ios

I use this code below to take a snapshot of a view. It works in most case but not for a view contains a UIDatePicker.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *snapshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The view is :

[image]

The image it generates looks weird :

[image]

Can anybody tell me why this happens and how to take snapshot of a view contains `UIDatePicker`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: @demon9733 user1390486's answer works.

Comment: @NicolasJakubowski  user1390486's answer works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the layer's renderInContext method, use this:

```
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm sorry it's so late to accept the answer. It works on iOS7 and iOS9, I don't have other device just tested on the two system versions.

Answer (score 0):

Set opaque = NO in your call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`()

Comment: It doesn't work. `CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ;`
`CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1.0) ;`

Comment: Works for me. OS version ?

Comment: iOS 7.1.1 . If you didn't set opaque to NO, Would you have the same issue as mine.